# A generic error occured in GDI+ while saving image

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing

I have to save an image in  `post` request in `byte64String` format 
when i save that image i get  `A generic error occurred in GDI+`

here is my code

```
byte[] ix = Convert.FromBase64String(obj.Image);

var ID = obj.Id;

using (var mStream = new MemoryStream(ix))
{
var img = Image.FromStream(mStream);

var image = obj.ImageName + ".jpg";
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Images/" + ImageType + "/" + ID + "/" + image);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);


try
{
   img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
var d = e;
}
}
```

**also 
this is not a permission issue as i am able to create text files in the same directory**

Comment: Write the bytes to a file using `File.WriteAllBytes`, and see if there is a valid image in there, my suspicion is its not what you think it is. also format your code, its unreadable

Comment: yes there is a valid image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply you are confusing paths and filenames.

The problem if could hazzard a guess, you probably have a folder that is your filename, and you are trying to save a file with that same name, which windows forbids

Your code tweaked

```
var image = $"{obj.ImageName }.jpg";

// get the path, and only the path
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/Images/{ImageType}/{ID}/");

// Create directory if needed (from that path)
Directory.CreateDirectory(path,image);

...

// now create the correct full path    
var fullPath = Path.Combine(path,fileName);

// save
img.Save(fullPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```